# Issue with connecting to Zoom API via Cloudflare

Tags: iis, cloudflare, zoom-sdk

I am trying to send requests to Zoom API via a HTTP request. When testing on my local machine it works perfectly but when I try it on our production server I get the following error:

msxml6.dll error '80072efe'
The connection with the server was terminated abnormally.

We use Cloudflare for security with our website, does anyone know what the resolution here maybe?
The server is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 using IIS 7.5.

Comment: That is probably not going through Cloudflare. Can you check what address you are getting when looking up Zoom's API?

Comment: The most common problem is your antivirus or firewall interfering with the connection or it can also be caused by a name resolution issue like when the hostname resolves to 127.0.0.1 (via local) and the webserver is bound to the public IP address only.
make sure you configure the hostname in iis with your public IP if you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue.
It wasn't CloudFlare, it was the server object I was using in my function.

I changed the following line from this:

`Set ServerXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

to this:

`Set ServerXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")`

Problem solved.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: @Benzine I see that you try to implement The zoom api in vbscript/classic ASP. Could you share the code/pages that you use? Is it possible? I'm stuck with obtain token and refresh and I want compare another approach. Thankyou